# Wicket 1.4.7 + Swarm + Hive + Wicomsec

Tags: https, wicket, jboss7.x, swarm, wasp

i have a problem when i click on my tab generated with wicket framework.

In the url instead of wicket:bookmarkablepage ---page class name appears wicket:interface:1:[component]
and i take a wicket Exception like this:

2020-10-14 09:32:24,365 ERROR [org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle] (default task-1) unable to find component with path rendicontazioniRatealiMenuItem:rendicontazioniRatealiLink on stateless page [Page class = it.reply.grif.internet.WaviLoginPage, id = 0, version = 0] it could be that the component is inside a repeater make your component return false in getStatelessHint(): org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: unable to find component with path rendicontazioniRatealiMenuItem:rendicontazioniRatealiLink on stateless page [Page class = it.reply.grif.internet.WaviLoginPage, id = 0, version = 0] it could be that the component is inside a repeater make your component return false in getStatelessHint()

what is the problem?

i am not expert with wicket but our application is accessible through internet and all the pages are secured with wasp swarm and hive framework.
In my local environment the application work correctly, in system environment don't.
Probably is a problem of HTTP instead of HTTPS protocol?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with your application in deployment mode? Use `-Dwicket.configuration=deployment` as JVM parameter